# JQuery Datatables.net thead sorting image removal

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

I am using DataTables 1.10.12. I implemented it using MVC framwork. My problem is I have 25 columns in the table which I can accomodate on the same page if I do not have the sorting images in the . To remove them I have tried the following:

```
 <table id="datatable-buttons-por" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead style="font-size:smaller; background:none">
                    <tr>
```

And following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var handleDataTableButtons = function () {
                if ($("#datatable-buttons-por").length) {
                    $("#datatable-buttons-por").DataTable({
                        dom: "Bfrtip",
                        buttons: [
                          {
                              extend: "copy",
                              className: "btn-sm"
                          },
                          {
                              extend: "csv",
                              className: "btn-sm"
                          },
                          {
                              extend: "excel",
                              className: "btn-sm"
                          },
                          {
                              extend: "pdfHtml5",
                              className: "btn-sm"
                          },
                          {
                              extend: "print",
                              className: "btn-sm"
                          },
                        ],
                        responsive: true
                    });
                }
            };

            TableManageButtons = function () {
                "use strict";
                return {
                    init: function () {
                        handleDataTableButtons();
                    }
                };
            }();

            var $datatable = $('#datatable-checkbox');

            $datatable.dataTable({
                'order': [[1, 'asc']],
                'columnDefs': [
                  { orderable: false, targets: [0] }
                ]
            }); 
$datatable.on('draw.dt', function () {
                $('input').iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green'
                });
            });
            TableManageButtons.init();
            //$('#datatable-buttons-por thead').css('background-image', 'none');

            var table = $('#datatable-buttons-por').DataTable();
                        table.columns().every(function () {
                        var column = this;
                        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                            .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                            .on('change', function () {
                                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                    $(this).val()
                                );

                                column
                                    .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                    .draw();
                            });

                        column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                        });
                    });
        });
        $('#datatable-buttons-por thead th').css('background-image', 'none');
```

in Javascript.

Seems like none of these working. What I am doing wrong here? By the way, I still want to keep my sorting functionality enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the `th` not the `thead`

try:

```
$('#datatable-buttons-por thead th.sorting').css('background-image', 'none');
```

Comment: I tried to do that as well. Here is the full javascript for you (Updated the main post). Last line is your suggestion. Still it is showing those sorting images.